# Python: How to solve list index out of range error for python opencv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, video, keras

I am the beginner for Python.
How to solve this error?
I tried to find out the error but still cannot solve it.
How to increase the list index range?
I wonder whether there is a solution to increase the list index range?
I keep getting the error list index out of range. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
import cv2     # for capturing videos
import math   # for mathematical operations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # for plotting the images
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing import image   # for preprocessing the images
import numpy as np    # for mathematical operations
from keras.utils import np_utils
from skimage.transform import resize   # for resizing images
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm

# open the .txt file which have names of training videos
f = open("trainlist01.txt", "r")
temp = f.read()
videos = temp.split('\n')

# creating a dataframe having video names
train = pd.DataFrame()
train['video_name'] = videos
train = train[:-1]
train.head()

# open the .txt file which have names of test videos
f = open("testlist01.txt", "r")
temp = f.read()
videos = temp.split('\n')

# creating a dataframe having video names
test = pd.DataFrame()`enter code here`
test['video_name'] = videos
test = test[:-1]
test.head()
 
# creating tags for training videos
train_video_tag = []
for i in range(train.shape[0]):
    train_video_tag.append(train['video_name'][i].split('/')[0])
    
train['tag'] = train_video_tag

# creating tags for test videos
test_video_tag = []
for i in range(test.shape[0]):
    test_video_tag.append(test['video_name'][i].split('/')[0])
    
test['tag'] = test_video_tag


 # storing the frames from training videos
for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):
    count = 0
    videoFile = train['video_name'][i]
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Datasets/'+videoFile.split(' ')[0].split('/')[1])   # capturing the video from the given path
    frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate
    x=1
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        frameId = cap.get(1) >>current frame number
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if (ret != True):
            break
        if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
            # storing the frames in a new folder named train_1
            filename ='train_1/' + videoFile.split('/')[1].split(' ')[0] +"_frame%d.jpg" % count;count+=1
            cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
    cap.release()
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-25-e7d681bfa4b4> in <module>
      3     count = 0
      4     videoFile = train['video_name'][i]
----> 5     cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Datasets/'+videoFile.split(' ')[0].split('/')[1])   # capturing the video from the given path
      6     frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate
      7     x=1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here are [train list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X7g0.png) and [test list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51voi.png) contents

Comment: it means you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist...you should check what the output that line is, and what you're calling split on

Answer (score 2):

```
    # Lets take a look at a simple scenario that will cause index out of range error
    color = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'gray']
    # We know that the length of this array is 4 (but when indexing, it will go to 3, as array index starts from 0)
    
    for i, colorName in enumerate(color):
        print('Color at index: ', i, 'is: ', colorName)

    #Color at index:  0 is:  red
    #Color at index:  1 is:  green
    #Color at index:  2 is:  blue
    #Color at index:  3 is:  gray
        
    # Now lets try to access a non-existing color at index 9
    print ("Color at index 9 is: ", color[8])
```

Last line will give us error

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-a6c2d20bb636>", line 9, in <module>
    print ("Color at index 9 is: ", color[8])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why? Because we are trying to access something at the index that does not exist.

In you case, I will recommend to check the values of:

```
    # First you need to see what is the value of videFile, is it valid to be split? Is it empty, etc.
    print (videoFile)
    
    # This will tell you what the split() is giving you back
    print (videoFile.split(' '))

    # This will tell you, if [0] is a valid data or not
    print (videoFile.split(' ')[0])
    
    # This will tell you, if the split on '/' was successfull, as it should return some expected values, if it is empty, they you must figure out, is it expected or no
    print (videoFile.split(' ')[0].split('/'))
    
    # This is what you finally want, but before accessing the item at index 1, you need to make sure the date before it is present and is not empty. Also check are you accessing the item at right index, maybe it is [0] instead of [1]
    print (videoFile.split(' ')[0].split('/')[1])
```

Comment: FYI. the length of the color array is 4 not 3.

Comment: @fmw42 nice catch! Made the change.